# How to disable Spring async logging with logback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-logback

I am using spring boot for service development and logback for logging using slf4j

I have Async annotation on one of my classes that sometimes throws errors and logs them.
I don't want to log such error created by Async and would want to suppress such errors being logged on STDOUT.

I tried logging.org.springframework=false but in vain.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: what was the error message ?

Comment: it keeps logging and doesn't suppress the log.

Comment: Post the error you are seeing in logs,

Comment: Like I said, I don't see any errors and it doesn't log any. I just doesn't suppress the logs that I am trying to turn off

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the @Async annotation is used in class org.mypackage.MyClass.java you would specify an entry in your application.properties file declaring the desired log level. In your case 'OFF'.

`logging.level.org.mypackage.myclass=OFF`

Comment: that would suppress other custom logs as well in that class. Wouldn't it be better to just do logging.level.org.springframework=OFF? And you you had suggested didn't work with logback

Comment: Can you post a code example and describe the type of logging you do/don't want to see?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip logging in spring boot you can completely disable it by using 
logging.level.root=OFF
 logging.level.org.springframework.boot=OFF

Or you can turn of a spring boot LoggingSystem by setting 
System.property(SYSTEM_PROPERTY,NONE)
Here is link on LoggingSystem:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem.html

I think this may help